# My Media Query does not apply to the class

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a media query which looks like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .changePicture {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.changePicture {
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  float: right;
}
```

This is the class which is not in the media query. Now I have the problem that the query wont apply when the screensize is smaller than 1200px.

Comment: Your media query needs to go **after** your initial style - you need to override the normal style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change style before media query style to override.

```
.changePicture {
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .changePicture {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .changePicture{
     width: 15%;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 5%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-right: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, provide at least some explanation.

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why it should solve the problem.